# Segue from collection view cell to table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

This is giving me a very hard time. I am trying to segue from a collection view cell to a table view controller. When I click on a cell (specifically a button within a cell) I should be able to segue to the table view controller and have details of the cell clicked within the table view controller's cells.

In my view controller with the collection view cells, I have implemented a segue.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {       
        }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "details" {
    if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {

                if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath{
                    let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
                    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let posted = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [NSMutableArray: AnyObject]
                    let username = post["username"] as? String
                    let userpicuid = post["uid"] as? String
                    let userpostuid = posted["uid"] as? NSMutableArray
                    vc.username = username
                    vc.userpicuid = userpicuid
                    vc.posts = userpostuid
                     print(indexPath.row)
                }
            }}
```

When I segue, the userpic and username appear in the detailed table view just fine but they are not viewed within the table view cells. This is my code for the table view controller:

```
     var posts = NSMutableArray()
 @IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!

     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return self.posts.count

              }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UsersCell", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileTableViewCell

            //Configure the cell


            print(posts[indexPath.row])
            let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
            cell.Title.text = post["title"] as? String
            cell.Author.text = post["Author"] as? String
            cell.Price.text = post["Price"] as? String

            if let imageName = post["image"] as? String {

                let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")


                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {


                    }else {

                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }})}

            return cell
            }
```

Nothing shows up in the table view cell. I am new to swift and I have been trying so hard to find a solution to this but I can't.

Heres a picture of my database:
[image]

Comment: no need to implement `prepareforsegue` inside `didselectitem`

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the Delegate and Datasource of you tableview to the class?

Comment: i did set up the delegate and data source

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample that will navigate you to the `tableViewController` when user will tap on `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

// Change it with your required items.
return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

// Do not forgot to set cell tag.
cell.tag = indexPath.row//cell tag has been set to indexpath.row

return cell
}
```

In order to navigate to your `tableViewController` implement `PrepareForSegue` like mentioned below.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {

// Use this tag to pass data for the selected cell
//this tag will act as indexpath.row

guard let tag = (sender as? UIView)?.tag
else {
 return
}

// add the data you want to parse here.
print(tag)
}
}
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that you have set the segue in your storyboard file from `UICollectionViewCell` to your `UITableViewController`.

In case you required further details, please let me know i will add it to the answer.

Comment: I apologise, I don't think my question was clear enough. What I have already works fine. I am able to successfully segue from my collectionview to the tableviewcontroller. I know that I am successful in passing data because I was able to parse two data. The issue is that I want some data to be displayed in a tableviewcell in the tableviewcontroller but it is not working. I can parse data outside of tableviewcell for example, to a label but I am having difficulty parsing it to the actual tableviewcell @Maddy

Comment: What is the data in your`self.posts` array as you are not passing any data  to post array.

Comment: I am clicking on the cell, and a cell is a particular user in my database and by clicking the cell, I want to segue into a tableviewcontroller that has a list of all the post made by that particular user displayed in the tableviewcell. self.posts is a lost of all the post made by a particular user

Comment: r u getting empty records. share a single item with dummy data that are in your post array

Comment: when I want to pass data from collectionviewcells to my tableviewcell and display it in a label it is very easy I was able to pass a name when I click on the cell to a label using this simple code in viewDidLoad in my tableviewcontroller `self.Usersname.text = self.username`. I am just having a hard time passing data to a tableviewcell

Comment: have you checked that the delegate functions of tableView are executing

Comment: oh...I actually just incorporated a print statement in my nymberOfRowsInSection function and it is returning 0, which it shouldn't

Comment: yeah i was waiting  to hear this from you ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144275/discussion-between-juelizabeth-and-maddy).